# Undeclared variable

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I'm trying to create socket, and I should describe some structures:

```
(struct in_addr) addr;
addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
```

also I have included headers

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
```

But gcc says that there is an error:

```
error: ‘addr’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To declare a new `in_addr` struct, you need to remove those parentheses:

```
struct in_addr addr;
addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
```

What you have at the moment is a cast, which means (approx.) "assuming `addr` is already a declared variable of some other type, try to convert it to a `struct in_addr`".

Answer (score 1):

leave the parentheses out. just write

`struct in_addr addr;`